# Open source program that can reference a converted image to the html

Tags: html

I would like to know if there is a program that can reference a converted image file to the actual html?

What I mean is that normally when you save a html page, there will be image saved in the folder together with the html. Suppose that I need to convert the image to some other type (example from gif to jpg), then the actual html saved that contains that image will be lost since the image has been converted. I wanted to view the same html page with the image converted and the html page will still display the same image. As such, back to the question, i wonder if such program exists?

I have tried to google it but I have found no such program exists.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just changing the relevant `src` attribute in the `html` file?

Comment: I just want to change it in such a way say for example <img src="good.jpg"/>to <img src ="good.gif"/>